# Help with the sum of 1 from j=n-i+1 to n

Tags: summation

I'm having trouble understanding summation, specifically the following example:

$\sum^{n}_{j=n-i+1} 1$

If I plug this into WolframAlpha, I find that it sums to $i*n$, but I don't understand how to work through the problem myself. Since it's summing 1 within the specified indexes, I tried writing it out as $(n-i+1) + (n-i+1) + ... +(n-i+1)= n(n-i+1)$ but I don't think this is the right way to approach it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sum you have written, $$\sum_{j=n-i+1}^{n}1$$ is interpreted as $$\underbrace{1+1+...+1}_{n-(n-i+1)+1 \mbox{ times}} = \underbrace{1+1+...+1}_{(i-1)+1 \mbox{ times}}=\underbrace{1+1+...+1}_{i \mbox{ times}}=i$$

---

To give you a better example, we could write $$ 4 = 1+1+1+1 = \underbrace{1+1+1+1}_{(4-1)+1 \mbox{ times}}=\sum_{j=1}^{4} 1$$ This is a  special case of your question, with $n=4$ and $i=4$

Comment: Thank you! The special case helped. One remaining question (that might be a little stupid) in regard to the general case is how you go from "n-(n-i+1)+1 times to i times". Subtracting out the "n" makes sense, but why is it that you can rewrite "(-i+1)+1" as "(i-1)+1"?

Comment: Sure, so the first identity we need to see is the distribution of the negative into the bracket, therefore reversing everyone's sign: $-(n-i+1)=(-n+i-1)$.  Then, we can see that $n-(n-i+1)+1=n+(-n+i-1)+1 = n-n+i-1+1 = i$

Comment: Ah, that totally makes sense. Thank you so much!